# How to transfer an array from a pointer to the main program on C

Tags: arrays, c, pointers

This is the program I've been trying to run...

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define MAX 10

int suma_arreglo(int x1[], int x2[], int y);

int array1[] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10}, array2[] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10};
int *suma;

main()
{
    int cont = 0;

    suma = suma_arreglo(array1, array2, MAX);
    for(cont = 0; cont < MAX; cont++)
    {
        printf("\n%d + %d = %d", array1[cont], array2[cont], *suma++);
    }


    puts("");
    system("pause");
}


int suma_arreglo(int x1[], int x2[], int y)
{
    int cont, arraysum[y];

    for(cont = 0; cont < y; cont++)
    {
        arraysum[cont] = x1[cont] + x2[cont];
        //printf("\n%d + %d = %d", x1[cont], x2[cont], arraysum[cont]);
    }

    return arraysum;

}
```

But for some reason, it doesn't work, debugging I notice that the function and the program works fine, but the problem starts when I try to return the address arraysum to a pointer in the main program suma... in theory it should be

`suma = arraysum`

That way it works on the main program.  In any case, I think there is still an issue on the way I try to get back the data of the array to the main program.

What do you guys think?

Comment: Two problems: First of all `suma_arreglo` is declared an `int` **value**, not a pointer to an `int` (which would be `int *`). Secondly you attempt to return a pointer to the first element of the **local** array `arraysum`. Once the function returns the life-time of `arraysum` ends and any pointer to it or its elements becomes invalid. Pass a pointer to an existing array as an argument instead,

Answer (score 0):

This works:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#define MAX 10

int* suma_arreglo(int x1[], int x2[], int y, int* sum_arr_ptr);

int array1[] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10}, array2[] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10};
int *suma;

int sum_array1[MAX];

main()
{
    int cont = 0;

    suma = suma_arreglo(array1, array2, MAX, sum_array1);
    for(cont = 0; cont < MAX; cont++)
    {
        printf("\n%d + %d = %d", array1[cont], array2[cont], *suma++);
    }


    puts("");
    system("pause");
}


int* suma_arreglo(int x1[], int x2[], int y, int* sum_arr_ptr)
{


    for(int cont = 0; cont < y; cont++)
    {
        sum_arr_ptr[cont] = x1[cont] + x2[cont];
        //printf("\n%d + %d = %d", x1[cont], x2[cont], arraysum[cont]);
    }

    return sum_arr_ptr;

}
```

The issues were that firstly, you gave the function a return type of `int` and then made it return an `int*`. Secondly, it was returning its own local variable. Variables created locally inside function bodies disappear after the function finishes, so you can't return those.

Here I just introduce a fourth parameter to the function, an `int*` pointer to an array of ints so that it has a proper result to return at the end, instead of returning something that won't exist after the function returns. Also fixed the return type from `int` to `int*`.

PS. You can use the `static` keyword when creating a variable inside functions to extend its lifetime beyond the function body itself. In that case, the variable is initialized only once and lives until the end of the program.

Comment: Man! Thank you so much!  

It makes a lot of sense what you said about the return type, I just didn't think about it.  I just start learning to program and I feel really stuck on that program.  I need to study more the thing about the fourth parameter, maybe even experiment with it. 

In any case, your program run, thank you. Now I know how to return pointer values from functions

;)

Comment: You're welcome bro :) if you want more help you can just add me on Discord: KevinDaGrim#9485